# Building an API, keeping client access token safe

Tags: api, oauth

I'm building an API to be consumed by an iOS application. Consuming applications will be issued an access token.

The access token will be used to make SSL requests to our API, and these requests will originate from an iOS device.

Using Charles however, anyone running the client's application on their phone can de-encrypt the outgoing requests and see what the access token is.

What I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around is, how is it possible to keep that access token safe, even using SSL? Couldn't someone obtain the access code, incorporate it in their own application, and begin sending requests with that access token as if they were the original client?

What am I missing here?